# Series that converges or not (for m to infinity), based on choice of parameter j that depends on m.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following expression

$A_j(m) = \dfrac{2m+1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{j^2}{2m^2}$ for $j\in 1,...,2m$

If I set $j=1$ then this series converges to $0$ for $m\rightarrow\infty$, but if I set $j=2m$ it diverges. For $j=m-1$ it diverges as well. Since I could also write any number $j$ as $m-x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{N}$ I'm a bit confused about for which $j$ this series converges exactly. Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limits involving several variables are not a question of converging/diverging. Asking what $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m)$ is **makes no sense** without stating how $j$ behaves. If nothing is said, then the standard assumption should be that $j$ is a constant. In that case, it's easy to see that $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m) = 0$.

But as you noted yourself, there are many ways how $j$ can depend on $m$ that give different results. In addition to what you found, if you set $j = \lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m) = \frac12.$ But if you set $j = \lfloor \sqrt[4]{m} \rfloor$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m) = 0$ again.

So if you consider $j$ not constant but somehow dependent on $m$, it depends on exactly how to find the limit (if it exists at all). Sometimes one can make statements about certain classes of dependencies between $j$ and $m$. For example, if $\lim\sup \frac{j_m}m > 0$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m)$ will diverge, but if $j_m=o(\sqrt{m})$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m) = 0.$

In other words, finding out if $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_j(m)$ exists and what it is is still dependent on how $j$ changes with respect to $m$, and how much you know about that.